# Linux PowerPC Book E reserve pristine RAM through warm reboot

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, powerpc

With `CONFIG_FSL_BOOKE` (P1020 RDB) 2.6.31 I need to reserve 1MB of RAM at some fixed location (doesn't matter where) that is pristine, meaning it is not touched by U-Boot or the bootmem allocator, so that the RAM contents survive warm reboot. With the caveat that I cannot change U-boot to use `CONFIG_PRAM`/`mem=`.

Compiling relocatable kernel is not an option in arc/powerpc 2.6.31. `memmap` is not supported in arch/powerpc/kernel/setup_32.c.

Ideally this area should be reserved and not L1 d-cached, so that it can be used to store ramoops from interrupt context.

Is there any way to move `_end` out to 0x600000 before bootmem to create a hole that is not touched by anyone? That is, to trick the kernel into thinking that `_end` is farther out?

In vmlinux.lds.S I tried something like:

```
    . = ALIGN(PAGE_SIZE);
    _end = . ;
    PROVIDE32 (end = .);
```

Changed to

```
    . = ALIGN(PAGE_SIZE);
    _start_unused_ram = .;
    . = ALIGN(0x400000);
    _end = . ;
    PROVIDE32 (end = .);
```

However, the area between `__bss_stop` and 0x400000 was overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to add the area of memory as a reserved region in the device tree.

That way it will be reserved early during boot and should not be touched by the kernel.

Comment: Apparently you mean define a hole in RAM using the "memory" tag in the kernel arch/powerpc/boot/dts/<my board>.dts. This is the "correct" answer in that it does not involve kernel source code. However most Freescale SoC boards, including mine, ignore this and configure RAM in u-boot ddr.c. What I need is a politically incorrect kernel hack to fake either _end, RAM disk start, or size of board info structure. It seems that faking the size of the board info struct is best.

Comment: I don't know u-boot well, so you're probably right, though I wonder how that works in general if memory reserves are ignored.

The other option would be to explicitly call `memblock_reserve()` (probably `lmb_reserve()` in 2.6.31), somewhere in the early boot code.

Comment: The "correct" answer is per @mpe: In 2.6.31:arch/powerpc/kernel/prom.c add another call to lmb_reserve after the call to phyp_dump_reserve_mem. Make sure that your bootloader is not configured to do a memtest that would erase the area that you reserve before starting the boot sequence.